# Values of index in getAddressLine (int index)

Tags: java, google-geocoder

I am developing a mobile app in android studio which collects user's location information (lat and lon) and geocode it to get the address information. I am able to get the country name and admin area which I presume to represent the state/province. but then, I need to get only the road name, in this case, the getAddressLine method returns the full address. I notice the address line accepts an index number that must be 0 and above but I want to know what is the maximum number to provide as index and what each value represents.

I have tried putting different numbers, but I want to know what values of `index` return which parameter.

```
String road_name = "";
String state = "";
String country = "";
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
 try {
  List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, 
  longitude, 1);
  if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size(index) > 0) {
   road_name += listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
   state += listAddresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
   country += listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Hmm one question, lat, lon, address, country, etc, all is coming inside a JSON? or how is it coming, can you post an example of the "string" that is holding all this values?

Comment: The structure of `Address` is effectively hidden as it is just a class from a library: `android.location.Address`.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr You gotta parse the String out yourself. There is no method for what you want.**

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address#getAddressLine(int)):

> Returns a line of the address numbered by the given index (starting at 0), or null if no such line is present.

So that index designates which line of the address to return, in the case that the address has multiple lines. It does not refer to a specific part of an address line.

You would have to parse that out yourself, as I did not see anything like `getStreetName` in the docs.

You may benefit from investigating [getThoroughfare()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address#getThoroughfare()), but even that would still need to be parsed by you.